# how to pan and zoom part of a large image using xy-coordinates without using the createBitmap method?

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, zooming

I am loading a panaroma 360 image from my drawable folder to my imageView and i want to pan and zoom specific part of that large image using 4 corner xy-coordinates. I want a solution that does not use the createBitmap() method because i do not want to reconstruct a new bitmap every time as i am passing new coordinates very often and creating a new bitmap takes considerable time for my liking,i just want to pan and zoom into a already existing image.

Comment: use `Canvas#scale` or `Canvas#concat` or `Canvas#drawBitmap(Bitmap, Matrix, Paint)`

Comment: Yeah 'canvas' looks like the right way to go instead of the 'imageView'. Thank u :)